# Запись в SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Имеется 2 layots в каждом по 1 TextVield и 1 Button.

Как из 1 layots записать данные в одну таблицу, например в поле Number, а во-втором так-же только во 2 таблицу.
Если можно выложите на файлообменник простенький примерчик.

Answer (score 1):

[Работа с базой данных Android](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/01/android.html)